# Tridion Core Service - create component issue

Tags: core-service, c#

I try to CRUD components in an ASP.NET MVC 4 project using Tridion Core Service

First, I read a configuration component :

```
var publicationData = client.Read("tcm:180-278202", new ReadOptions()) as ComponentData;

var componentData = new ComponentData
{
    Content = publicationData.Content,
    ComponentType = ComponentType.Normal,
    Title = "random title",
    Schema = new LinkToSchemaData { IdRef = "tcm:179-277976-8" },
    LocationInfo = new LocationInfo { OrganizationalItem = new LinkToOrganizationalItem { IdRef = "tcm:179-109377-2" }},
    Id = "tcm:0-0-0"
};

client.Save(componentData, new ReadOptions());
```

I get an error message on the **Client.Save** with the following message :

(translated from dutch) Unexpected stem? element : Content. Expected : uuid:1d939ee2-29e5-4a94-b378-5c6420d6d46f:Configuration

The uuid is the same except that there is no ":Configuration" at the end

Every suggestion is welcome.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The schema has (at least) one mandatory field named "Configuration", and your code is not setting any field values, so the content fails XML validation.

You need to add content to your `componentData.Content` and make sure it's valid according to schema before you can save it. Check if publicationData.Content includes the "Configuration" field?

Comment: Actually the schema changed during the time I wasn't on this project, that's why I searched a tag 'configuration' that didn't exist, I checked and now it's working, thanks

Answer (score 4):

Rather than building the component manually, a more robust approach is to request the default information from Tridion using

```
client.GetDefaultData(ITEM_TYPE, CONTAINER_TCM_ID);
```

This is create the component based on the container, populating all mandatory fields with the default values.

So in your case something like

```
var publicationData = client.Read("tcm:180-278202", new ReadOptions()) as ComponentData;

var componentData = client.GetDefaultData(ItemType.Component, "tcm:179-109377-2") as ComponentData; 

componentData.Content = publicationData.Content; //with configuration field set
componentData.Title = "Title";
componentData.Schema = new LinkToSchemaData { IdRef = "tcm:179-277976-8" }

client.Save(componentData, new ReadOptions());
```